# Tomcat: set maximum connection for particular servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

In my webapp, I have a servlet which is mostly used. I'm using Blocking IO protocol in my tomcat and set maxConnection as 150. So what happens is, that particular servlet holds all the connection and I can't load the Client side in browser.

Idea 1: I'm trying to forward the request for the particular to Connector which listens on another port. Is this possible in Tomcat?

Idea 2: Can we set maximum tomcat threadpool size for particular servlet.

Any other idea also welcome.

**Note: I don't want to use any other tool like nginx**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider deploying this servlet in its own tomcat instance?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @fujy, I can't understand "deploying in its own tomcat instance". Can you please explain briefly for me.

Comment: Run two tomcat servers, make one for that heavy servlet.

Comment: Ohhh no, Actually the client will make call from remote machine. So I don't want them to make change. I need to forward the request to another port (or) I need to process the request in separate thread pool

Comment: @Gokul: you can use a [`Filter`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/filter) to limit the number of concurrent requests to a particular servlet. However, if the servlet has long lasting requests, consider using Servlet 3.0 Async API and process the requests on a thread pool you create.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @PiotrP.Karwasz, how does using Servlet 3.0 Async API solve the problem with long lasting request. However I need to send response back, I need to process the request. So obviously it will take some time. Can you please explain how Servlet 3.0 Async API works?